# Is it possible to install Ubuntu Server 10.04 *from* a USB drive?

Tags: usb, installation, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-server

I've tried the Universal USB Installer from PenDrive, and put 10.04 Ubuntu Server on it. But when I boot up and try to install, it looks for a Ubuntu CD ROM, which I do not have.

I thought the whole point is to be able to install from a USB, which seems easy with the Desktop version. Why is the server version not allowing me to do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Tried using UNetBootin - http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Ubuntu Server by downloading the iso and using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1, unetbootin worked with everything I tried to feed it.

Comment: Using unetbootin, managed to create a LiveUSB of Ubuntu 10.04. When I boot to it, there is an option to install. I've never tried it, but I guess it's possible.

Comment: unetbootin doen't work with Ubuntu 10.04, there are bugs in the program which cause it to create unusable sticks.

Answer (score 2):

There have been a lot of problems getting 10.04 server to install from a usb-drive, apparently  there are bugs in the unetbootin program that truncate file names.

This guy seems to have [figured out most of the issues](http://blog.smalleycreative.com/linux/fix-for-ubuntu-10-04-server-usb-install/)

Haven't tried it all yet myself, still working on it myself.

Alternatively using Ubuntu's [usb-creator-gtk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) program may work better. Found [this page about it too](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent).

Comment: After having the same problems with the 10.04.3 LTS Server installation, the steps in the linked blog solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did install it using usb startup creator (usb-creator: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#From%20Ubuntu%20Linux) from another pc with Ubuntu or from a Ubuntu desktop live cd.

You start the creator, select the iso (I've used ubuntu server alternate install) and prepared the usb pen.

Then booted from it.

IMPORTANT:

just a few times I've had problems which were really strangely solved inserting in the very first boot screen the word "help" and pressing enter.
After viewing a very fast help page I was able to flawlessly install.

Answer (score 0):

I install all my *nix servers with a USB key. Have a look at [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and have fun !

YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Integrator) can be used to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive containing multiple operating systems, antivirus utilities, disc cloning, diagnostic tools, and more. YUMI uses syslinux to boot extracted distributions stored on the USB device, and reverts to using grub to Boot Multiple ISO files from USB, if necessary.

Hints : be sure to select another drive than /dev/sda (your USB key !) in order to install Grub ... or you will need it to boot your favorite disto !

Answer (score -1):

short answer: supposidly yes

longer answer: from what I am finding there are many "use my way" options but I havn't personaly tried any recently...I HAVE gotten ubuntu netbook remix and vanilla ubuntu to be installed off a usb key. but as my uncle told me years ago...some usb keys just don't work with some machines.... so I again answer...supposidly there is a way...but it is kinda hunt and peck to see if you can find one that works for you =D

Comment: You want to expand on that ?